# Google Maps V2 crashes after updating to api 19

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

Everything works fine until I update some items in sdk manager. Now whenever I try to run my app that has google maps, my app crashes.

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.prototype"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="test.prototype.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="test.prototype.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="test.prototype.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="test.prototype.MapDetail" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myApiKey" />

         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);  

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);                                                                                                             
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));

        TextView coordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
        coordinates.setText("Latitude: " +  latitude  + "\n" + "Longitude: "+ longitude );        
    }   

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {

    }

}
```

**xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coordinates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/coordinates" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Ok so I've added

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in the manifest. Manifest updated.

But there's still an error:

```
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.prototype/test.prototype.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at test.prototype.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
02-25 05:18:31.026: E/AndroidRuntime(6265):     ... 11 more
```

**LogCat** updated after running it on my other device:

```
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.prototype/test.prototype.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at test.prototype.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     ... 11 more
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at maps.e.ch.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at maps.e.bf.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at eio.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
02-25 05:38:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4342):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: What line is line 28? That's where you NullPointerException is.

Comment: googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [SupportMapFragment.getMap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMap%28%29), it returns

> `null` if the view of the fragment is not yet ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

Consider [configuring your initial state via XML attributes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#configuring_initial_state) and moving your `getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true)` to your `onLocationChanged` to ensure that your Map has been laid out and configured, rather than doing it in `onCreate`

Comment: I tried what you said and run it on my other device but it still crashes. I'll post the new LogCat.

Comment: Looks like you are missing Manifest permissions.

Comment: Hehe. Thanks. I've added the two missing permissions said on the LogCa and it's working now :)

Comment: Ok. And I think the problem is on my other device. It crashes when I run it there. But it's working on my other device.

Comment: You might consider going through the steps on [ensuring Google Play Services is available](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure) as `getMap()` will also return null in those cases as well.